# Jquery how to get array from checked checkboxes

Tags: jquery, ajax, arrays

I need to pass data as an array to a fancybox instance in JQuery.

The passed format needs to look like this: `Array( [remove] => Array ( [1] => 1 [109] => 109 [110] => 110 ))`

Now I use the following code, but this doesn't work because I'm not passing an array.

Thanks in advance...

Checkboxes look like this and are generated on the database results:

```
<td class="checkboxTable"><input name="remove[<?php echo $users->id; ?>]" type="checkbox" id="checkbox[]" value="<?php echo $users->id; ?>"/></td>
```

The javascript I use is this:

```
$('.deleteConfirmationMultiple').Loader({
    url: ['/dgpcms/public/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.2.pack.js',
        '/dgpcms/public/fancybox/jquery.easing-1.3.pack.js',
        '/dgpcms/public/fancybox/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.4.pack.js',
        '/dgpcms/public/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.2.css'],
    ////debug: [true],
    cache: [true],
    success: function(target){
        $(this).fancybox({
            'autoDimensions'    : true,
            'autoScale'         : true,
            'overlayOpacity'    : '0.70',
            'overlayColor'      : '#000000',
            'transitionIn'      : 'none',
            'transitionOut'     : 'none',
            'hideOnOverlayClick': false,
            'hideOnContentClick': false,
            'showCloseButton'   : false,
            'href'              : $('#deleteConfirmation').attr('action'),
            ajax : {
                    type    : 'POST',
                    data    : $('input:checkbox:checked')
                }
        });
    }
});
```

Is there a way to pass the values exactly as PHP would do it (like this: `Array ( [remove] => Array ( [1] => 1 [109] => 109 [110] => 110 ) [deleteMultiple] => Delete selected )`)?

**EDIT 12 Jan 2011**

I got a bit further, but nof there is a weird problem..

Id isn't posted as data in my ajax call. When I create an onclick function for the checkall link (all checkboxes get selected) and call the getData function and alert the result, I get the id's of the checked boxes. But calling the function in my ajax call returns empty...

Here is the code:

```
$('.deleteConfirmationMultiple').Loader({
    url: ['/dgpcms/public/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.2.pack.js',
        '/dgpcms/public/fancybox/jquery.easing-1.3.pack.js',
        '/dgpcms/public/fancybox/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.4.pack.js',
        '/dgpcms/public/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.2.css'],
    ////debug: [true],
    cache: [true],
    success: function(target){
        // Array( [remove] => Array ( [1] => 1 [109] => 109 [110] => 110 ))
        // var id = {5: '5', 6: '6', 7: '7'};

        var id = '';
        $.fn.getData = function(options){
            var id = $('input:checkbox:checked').map(function(){
                return this.value.serialize();
            }).get();
            //alert(id);
            return id;
        };

        $(this).fancybox({
            'autoDimensions'    : true,
            'autoScale'         : true,
            'overlayOpacity'    : '0.70',
            'overlayColor'      : '#000000',
            'transitionIn'      : 'none',
            'transitionOut'     : 'none',
            'hideOnOverlayClick': false,
            'hideOnContentClick': false,
            'showCloseButton'   : false,
            'href'              : $('#deleteConfirmation').attr('action'),
            ajax : {
                    type    : 'POST',
                    data    : {'remove':id}
                    }
        });         
    }
});
```

**Edit 12 Jan 2010**

The code below, containing an array hardcoded works precisely as I want, Now I need to create the same thing from the checked checkboxes....

```
var id = {5: '5', 6: '6', 7: '7'};

        $(this).fancybox({
            'autoDimensions'    : true,
            'autoScale'         : true,
            'overlayOpacity'    : '0.70',
            'overlayColor'      : '#000000',
            'transitionIn'      : 'none',
            'transitionOut'     : 'none',
            'hideOnOverlayClick': false,
            'hideOnContentClick': false,
            'showCloseButton'   : false,
            'href'              : $('#deleteConfirmation').attr('action'),
            ajax : {
                    type    : 'POST',
                    data    : {'remove':id}
                    }
        });
```

Comment: select checked ones and use each to store their values in an array?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure the *exact* format you want to pass, but to get an array instead of just this:

```
$('input:checkbox:checked')
```

...which gets a set of elements (a jQuery object), use [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) to get an array of their values, like this:

```
$('input:checkbox:checked').map(function() { return this.value; }).get();
```

Comment: Doesn't work. If I alert the values all I get to see is 109,110

Comment: @Rick - That's an array of the values...what do you *expect* to see?

Comment: The script to which the data is send uses $_POST['remove'] to look for corresponding items in the database (the numbers are id's) and then an user can delete these. When I user $(.input:checkbox') alle checkboxes are send and can be deleted; I only want the checked ones; $('input:checkbox:checked') doesn't work. So I figured to pass the data the same way as PHP would on posting the form. Hences the array. But maybe I'm doing this totally wrong...

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.map()` for this:

```
var data = $('input:checkbox:checked').map(function(){
    return this.value;
}).get();
```

This will give an array of the format `['109', '110']`.

Comment: Doesn't work. If I alert the values all I get to see is 109,110

Comment: @Rick Please see the last line of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

By reviewing everything again, and using the fancybox login example I came up with the following code which works precisely how I wanted:

```
$('.deleteConfirmationMultiple').Loader({
    url: ['/dgpcms/public/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.2.pack.js',
        '/dgpcms/public/fancybox/jquery.easing-1.3.pack.js',
        '/dgpcms/public/fancybox/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.4.pack.js',
        '/dgpcms/public/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.2.css'],
    //debug: [true],
    cache: [true],
    success: function(target){

        $(this).click(function()
        {
            var id = $('input:checkbox:checked').map(function(){
                return this.value;
            }).get();
            //alert(id);

            $.ajax({
                type    : "POST",
                url     : $('#deleteConfirmation').attr('action'),
                data    : {'remove':id},
                success: function(data) {
                    $.fancybox(data,
                    {
                        'autoDimensions'    : true,
                        'autoScale'         : true,
                        'overlayOpacity'    : '0.70',
                        'overlayColor'      : '#000000',
                        'transitionIn'      : 'none',
                        'transitionOut'     : 'none',
                        'hideOnOverlayClick': false,
                        'hideOnContentClick': false,
                        'showCloseButton'   : false
                    });
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    }
});
```